# Perl how do I dynamically alias a sub and pass it arguments?

Tags: perl

In Perl how do I dynamically alias a sub and pass it arguments?
Or How do I alias a sub to another sub in a blessed object?
I have an array @files that I would like to all become subs that call sub log with the name of the file appended to @_
Sample code with things I tried below.
Is this possible? Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                             
#https://www.perl.com/article/closures-as-objects/
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;

package Debug;
use Data::Dumper;
sub new {
  my $self = {};
  # How do I alias all @files to sub log ?
  my @files = (qw(callback log printing ));
  foreach my $file (@files){
    # updated with ikegami's proposed answer
    $self->{$file} = sub { plog( @_, $file ) }; 
  }
  print Dumper $self;
  return bless $self;
}

sub plog { # provides Debug->log Debug->printing Debug->status etc..
    my ($self, $level, $message, $file) = @_;
    print "Level:'$level'\n";
    print "Message:'$message'\n";
    print "File:'$file'\n";
    
}

1;

###################################################

package main;
  


my $debug = Debug->new();

#       file        level, message
$debug->plog(1,"Hello World","were in the Debug" );
$debug->callback(1,"Hello World" );
$debug->log(1,"Hello World" );
$debug->printing(1,"Hello World" );
#### Desired result
# Level:1
# Message:Hello World
#File:callback
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl objects don't have the methods of their own; they have the methods of their class.

```perl
package Debug;

use Sub::Name qw( subname );

for my $name (qw( callback log printing )) {
   my $sub = subname $name, sub {
      my $self = shift;
      return $self->plog( @_ , $name );
   };

   no strict qw( refs );
   *$name = $sub;
}

...
```

or

```perl
package Debug;

sub callback { my $self = shift; $self->plog( @_, "callback" ) }
sub log      { my $self = shift; $self->plog( @_, "log"      ) }
sub printing { my $self = shift; $self->plog( @_, "printing" ) }

...
```

Comment: Very cool thank you! My @files array is huge in the real program so this helps me avoid tons of code!

Comment: Using `subname` isn't required, but will result in much better error messages if a problem happens.

Answer (score 1):

> put log function here?

You want to put a *call* to `log` there.

```perl
$self->{ $file } = sub { log( @_, $file ) };
```

It's called as follows:

```perl
$debug->{ callback }->( ... )
```

Comment: Thanks that seems right but I get the error Can't locate object method "callback" via package "Debug", and I should add I had to change the function log to plog as i think it was trying to call perls log function.

Comment: I have updated the code now with your proposed answer but I get 'Can't locate object method "callback" via package "Debug" at ./dynamic_function.pl line 41.'

Comment: You set `$debug->{ callback }`, so you would need `$debug->{ callback }->{ ... )`.